# How to copy generated content on a website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, scrape

I am trying to copy the HTML part of a website and for that I would usually use a google developer tools (inspect element would be the case).
But this site changes it's content while scrolling down (the old content gets replaced by new one even for a small scroll)

I need all of this tag to be saved/copied.

This would be the tag

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 7960px;"></div>
```

As you see, based on the height, it changes content...
Any idea how to grab all of it?

Thank you!

Comment: give the parent div that has some unique id

Comment: If the website "changes its's content as you scroll" it probably keeps fetching more and more data to the page live by requesting it from the server. You'd probably want to mess around with the tool Selenium to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hmmm you mean this one:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/ ?

Comment: Or you can use beatifulsoup library.

Comment: The website in question is discord...I highly doubt I could do that with bs4...